# How can I efficiently run through this data?

Tags: sql, t-sql, cursor

I need to find the average values of col2, based on col1. Currently I have a cursor to run through the data, but it's extremely inefficient and I'm not sure how to effectively use a while loop to run through the data. Here is the first part of the data:

```
Col1      Col2   
2           12  
2           43  
2           49  
2           51  
3           51  
3           49  
3           43  
3           12  
5           12  
5           12  
5           43  
5           49  
5           51  
6           51  
6           49  
6           43  
6           12  
7           12  
7           12  
7           43  
7           51  
7           49
```

Column 1 should not have any repeat values after the query is done. The idea is to just average out all the numbers in col2 using col1 as a guide.

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Hint #2 `avg()`

Comment: Hint #Abstract for 1&2 above: process data in data sets not record by record.  a `GROUP BY` will GROUP like values into one value for the columns listed.  `AVG()` is an aggregate function which takes the value of a column specified and "Averages" for the columns defined in the group by.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use avg and group by

```
  select col1, avg(col2)
  from my_table 
  group by col1
```

Comment: I was missing the "group by" clause. And now I feel stupid